# View Engine for ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what are the things to consider before choosing a View Engine for ASP.net MVC

Comment: duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649768/alternative-asp-net-mvc-view-engines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523644/what-templating-engines-are-available-for-asp-net-mvc-framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173207/best-template-engine-for-aspnet-mvc

Comment: They're not really duplicates.  Two of them ask what is the best engine (not the same question), and the third is an obscure technical question.

Comment: CW disussion in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

I was elaborating an answer for your question but i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison) wiki that is excelent to know what we have to consider before choosing a View Engine for ASP .net MVC.

I think the election depends too much about which is more comfortable for you.