# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio 2010 formatting C# code in ASP.NET MVC views?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

I'd like Visual Studio to continue automatically formatting my `.cs` files, but is there a way to prevent it auto-formatting C# code in between the `<% %>` tags in ASP.NET MVC views because it really makes a mess of it?

Comment: +1.  That's incredibly frustrating!

Comment: Has anyone tried this with VS2010 SP1 yet?  The beta was released in the last few days.

Comment: @Drew - not yet. If I get time I may fire up a VM and test this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there isn't a way to turn off the formatting just in ASP.NET files as it uses the rules for C# in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#.

Comment: Maybe in v.next they'll fix this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it and it is a huge time waster fixing up the formatting in .aspx pages over and over again. It drives me nuts.

There are two connect issues/bugs for this.  One was marked as fixed for months but the latest response does not look like anything was even done.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514691/add-aspx-or-inline-c-as-an-option-in-text-editor-formatting-options

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586729/support-c-formatting-options-for-aspx-pages

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (afaik), you can't have separate settings for C# in .cs and .aspx files.  You can change the settings for C# in Tools -> Options -> C# -> Formatting.

To get things to work well with MVC, I changed some settings in the New Lines section.  I unchecked the boxes for control block, object initializers, and "else".  This produces the walk-like-an-egyptian style braces that works best in MVC code, without screwing too much with my normal C# code.  I leave the settings for functions, classes etc. alone since you don't normally define those in an .aspx file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a fiddle about with these settings.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider using Razor as your View Engine instead of aspx.

see also:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx (Scott Guthrie)
- [ASP.NET MVC Razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174786/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-engine) (StackOverflow)

Comment: Makes no difference to the formatting problem with VS - it makes a hash of Razor views too.

Comment: @JonathanMoffatt if you use spaces instead of tabs you should be fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267165/visual-studio-2010-code-formatting-in-cshtml-improper-indentation