# Visual Studio 2010 Code Formatting in .CSHTML - Improper Indentation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, razor

Pretty simple problem to explain: In Visual Studio 2010 SP1, I'm seeing weird indentation issues with braces when using Razor.

Here's how it looks:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                @if (true)
        {
                    <b>Hi</b> 
       }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's what comes out after I do a CTRL + K, D to format it.  Anyone else have this issue?  What's the deal?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can confirm the problem. We're calling the key combination "control-kill-death" currently...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a known bug in the editor.

To fix it, select `Insert Spaces` rather than `Keep Tabs` in Options, Text Editor, HTML.

Comment: Horray for fix, boo to spaces.

Comment: Seriously? Was that it? Nice, but too bad with spaces. I guess I can learn to live with it, but I shouldn't have to conform to the tool, it should be the other way around :(

Comment: By the way, here's the Connect issue on this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637445/razor-editor-with-keep-tabs-turned-on

Comment: Argh, I hate using spaces. Hope they fix this soon, so I can go back to using tabs again.

Comment: that Connect link is marked Closed as duplicate. Here's the original - though it is marked closed as deferred :( http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650455

Comment: @Valamas: What fix? :) This is just a workaround that shouldn't be tolerated for too long. An **actual fix** should be implemented.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Yes, not a fix. And yes, should have been fixed as hot fix quickly. I think they vs2010 is abandoned as they are working on vs2011(or could be vs2012 by now). Could be time to have a play of that.

Comment: This had been annoying me for quite some time. Thanks for the solution.