# Is there a prescribed Castle Monorail to ASP.NET migration path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-monorail

Is there a straight forward migration path from Castle Monorail to ASP.MVC 2 or 3, or is this uncharted territory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this migration some time ago and it went smoothly. MonoRail is very close to ASP.NET MVC in terms of naming conventions. The most work was needed to migrate the Brail views to Razor. Also the concept of strongly typed views in MVC is nice and should be taken into account. But don't expect a step by step tutorial on how to do this because it will very much depend on the application.

Comment: That's good to hear, as I'm also about to undertake this pilgrimage. Why did you choose not to use the port of Brail? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt there is a *prescribed* path, or indeed any official path.