# Why is my code not evaluated as expected inside of a tag attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, virtual-directory

This code:

```
<% string path = Request.ApplicationPath.ToString(); %>
<link href="<%= path %>/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Returns this:

```
<link href="../Views/Shared/%3C%25=%20path%20%25%3E/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Whereas I was expecting this:

```
<link href="/foo/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why did my code not return the expected path? How do I set up my scripts, css files, and images to be flexible if my virtual directory changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, what view engine are you using?  Are you using MVC3, which I believe defaults to Razor and not Asp.Net for the view engine?

To answer your second question, you should try this:
`<link href="<%: Url.Content( "~/Content/Site.css" ) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

That should output what you want

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. As for view engine, how do I determine which one I'm using?

Comment: In your global.asax you can set the view engine.  If there's no code in there, you're probably using the default.  I think in MVC3 is Razor by default, earlier versions use WebForms.  You can check this out to find many other view engines:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison

Comment: I know this question is 5 years old, but for the record, I was using WebForms. :)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual paths can be specified using the ~ (tilde) prefix.