# Engines like MVC 3 RAZOR for MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have read many posts on here regarding this issue; The answers of  'Why would you want to do that' and 'just upgrade'.

Here is a reason for why I cannot just upgrade.

Where I work we don't have IIS7 yet. .NET 4.0 needs IIS7 and MVC 3 needs .net 4.0.

I creating a new applicaiton in MVC2 and would liek to know if there are solid engines that are like RAZOR?

(Please don't leave comments that ask questions like the ones above).

Comment: .NET 4 **does NOT** require IIS7. I'm happily running it under IIS6 (Win server 2003).

Comment: Really? I was under the impression that IIS 7 was needed.

Comment: Nope. Both mvc3 and .net 4 work fine.

Comment: We have to get .net 4.0 on our servers, but we will move forward with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/)

> Spark is a view engine for Asp.Net Mvc and Castle Project MonoRail
>   frameworks. The idea is to allow the html to dominate the flow and the
>   code to fit seamlessly.

You can also look at [MVC engines comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison)

Comment: For older applications we will use this. As per @David Lively, we will be using mvc3 for new stuff.