# ASPX Page = Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net

I started working with ASP.Net and I'm wondering: Are WebApplications with aspx Pages (like SharePoint) always based on Web Forms?

Because Web Forms are obsolet I've created a little MVC test project. It does not contain any aspx pages but cshtml pages.

Best Regards

Comment: show some research pls: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC

Answer (score 1):

ASPX can be used with MVC instead of Razor (cshtml) although it is not common. So no, being ASPX doesn't automatically make it Web Forms, though the majority of time it will be.

MVC has the concept of pluggable [View Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308485/what-is-view-engine-what-does-it-actually-do). Note that just because you can use the ASPX extension does not mean that all the controls that you can use in Web Forms will be available in MVC. Everything still follows the MVC lifecycle, not Web Forms.

Note that having .cshtml doesn't necessarily mean you're using MVC. It could be [Web Pages](https://www.asp.net/web-pages), [Razor PDF](http://nyveldt.com/blog/page/razorpdf) or some other framework.