# Internally, what is asp.net or asp.net mvc using to convert razor syntax to html?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know that the browser will understand only 3 languages, those are HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I read,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Example:

> @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
>
> @using mvcTestProject.Controller.Models.Example

And above razor syntax is how and who converts razor to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a Browser will mostly process the HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Razor syntax never makes it to the Browser. Razor engine parses the syntax and produces html on the server side which goes to the Browser and then the browser renders those as usual.

Razor view engine comes with the Dotnet framework (System.Web.Razor). It is written in C#.

You can read more about the View Engine here: [What is view engine? What does it actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308485/what-is-view-engine-what-does-it-actually-do)

Comment: Thanks buddy for reply It just said about razor engine but how? So what is the engine? what type of it? What language behind this engine to convert razor syntax to HTML?