# Can we broadcast .aspx extension in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a confusing question. I have to convert an ASP.NET Web application in ASP.NET MVC. Everything is going fine but problem is that, site owner wants that urls of pages should not be change means if any page have a url http://abc.com/a.aspx then its should be as it. 
Now I already told my team members that it is not possible to broadcast any extension like .aspx extension in ASP.NET MVC, but he told me to search it.
As I had did lot of search but did not find any way to perform it. 
Is it possible that we can broadcast .aspx extension in URL in ASP.NET MVC2 or 3 by some routing configuration so that page urls did not change.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways.  The easiest might be to use IIS Url Rewriting to rewrite any .aspx file to its equivelent MVC route.

A different way would be to simply create Routes that match a .aspx extension and route them to your Controller/Action.  ie:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}.aspx",  
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

The drawback here is that you can't use friendly parameters, well you could but it would probably break an existing URL.  they'd look like blah.com/blah/blah.aspx/blah.  Of course querystring parameters still work.

A third way would be to simply setup IIS to redirect any extension with .aspx to its equivelent MVC route.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this article:

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Hanselman also made a NuGet package that works great to get the ball rolling for you in a few clicks:

[AddMvc3ToWebForms](http://nuget.org/packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms)

I have personally used this NuGet package for a ASP.NET to MVC 3 conversion.  We were able to run both versions of the application at the same time from the same solution, very nice!

Comment: Hi @rick schott I had read links send by you but there is one confusion, whatever I understand it is an hybrid application which contains both asp.net and asp.net mvc application but it does not brodcast .aspx extension for views.   Thanks

Comment: You can configure MVC to use all kinds of View Engines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison