# what are the benefits of Razor over aspx exactly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, template-engine

I am working on MVC aspx since around a year. But could not go for Razor. I know there are the syntactical difference between aspx and razor. But could not understand the benefits. If it is just an alternative then why need it to be implemented exactly ?

Comment: This is a subjective discussion, it's like asking why C# over Java. I would say razor is a lot cleaner and you can switch between code/markup easily. But that's my opinion.

Comment: @ gideon: Thanks for share your thoughts. but is it beneficial in render view and make low in complexity, performance wise  ?

Comment: These posts might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699556/comparions-of-razor-vs-aspx-syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569809/mvc-3-aspx-vs-razor-view-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chk it out quite interesting [razor vs aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> **Unit Testable**: The new view engine implementation will support the
>   ability to unit test views (without requiring a controller or
>   web-server, and can be hosted in any unit test project – no special
>   app-domain required).
>   [Razor/CSHTML - Any Benefit over what we have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423732/razor-cshtml-any-benefit-over-what-we-have)