# Alternatives to Razor? Other ways how to avoid models duplication on client and server sides?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, knockout-mvc

Do we have any template engine alternative to Razor that integrates with Visual Studio and **could be executed on client side as well as on server side** ? 
That means the javascript should be used as a glue (not C#).

It seems that Razor now works like an anchor which stuck us thinking "server-side".

P.S. I've found that people have asked the same question different way: e.g. how to generate TypeScript from C# model. Some people interested in how to use T4 and CodeSmith for that.

P.P.S. Knockout.MVC did some steps that direction: it generates knockout binding from given C# model. I have found it difficult to integrate into existent project. Anything else?

Comment: All templating engines run server-side before the HTTP response gets sent. Not sure what you mean

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison) can help?

Comment: @beautifulcoder: All but not only. Even Razor can be processed client-side: https://github.com/jchadwick/RazorClientTemplates .

Comment: 2 minus? That what I said: thinking "always server-side".

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij The markup is still server-side! All this is doing is parsing HTML strings to a JavaScript variable

Comment: The mapping model to view could be done on client as well? Does it make any sense to you? Actually that is how Angular works.