# Can we use Slim html in Asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I was working on ruby on rails and was using slim html inside it and it was preety good. Now i am working on my final year project which is in Asp.net with mvc framework. My question is that can we use slim html in Asp.net to creat views ?

Answer (score 1):

Slim is built on ruby, so you'll need to use ruby to compile Slim to html. Your best bet might be to set up a script that runs during your build process and turns Slim templates into html. [NHaml](https://code.google.com/p/nhaml/) discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison) may be the closest thing you'll get in .Net land without a lot of trouble.