# Is it possible to use MVC without Asp.net pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I know that MVC is a design pattern that separates Model, View, Controller.
Model - Logic
View - Client View
Controller - connection between the two.

In case I want to change one of this things it will be easy just to change view\Model and the controller.

So is it possible to use only WebApi and MVC without Aps.Net pages (cshtml files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return html files

```
return new FilePathResult("path/FileName.html", "text/html");
```

And .cshtml files are Razor View Engine files, not Asp.Net pages.
You can alson change the view engine, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison) for a list of .net view egines.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, you can.

To elaborate: not sure what you mean, as .cshtml files are essentially the view part of MVC (the V part). ASP.NET MVC controllers by default return content of the .cshtml file by calling `View()` helper method.

But you can for example render html for the client inside your custom controller class without calling for a static html content. Or you might create WEB API project, with routing, models, and controllers, but no views - just plain data returned to the client.