# Razor on Active Directory Intranet App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, active-directory

I work on a big Active Directory Project where I need to remake the whole intranet application using ASP.NET MVC. I was wandering if Razor was a necessity here ? Especially for forms, I'm having a hard time with Razor forms (what a noob).

I have read that Razor is essential for scalable applications, which I guess is the case here, but if I could dodge this ugly stuff, that would be great.
In the end, do I need to use it for everything?

I have seen examples on the net that use classic HTML forms, and Razor for conditions and such. I don't mind using it for conditions, I just can't figure out how to render my forms with it. Is it ok to use normal html forms, or will it create some scalability issues in the future when I have 1 billion documents? :)

Thanks for your help, hope this isn't too redundant, I've seen this subject all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Razor Html Helpers to generate form/input tags (you can use standard HTML markup), but you'll miss out on some of the benefits (specifically integration with a viewmodel to pre-populate fields, validation, etc). You'll also need to make sure your input names match up properly when capturing the FORM POST on the submission side.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you want you want to go with.

This can help you decide.[View Engine Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison#1451355)