# ASP.NET MVC "View" coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm extremely annoyed with the way Visual Studio works when I write inline C#/MVC in the View. I think the source is horrendous to look at, and I wonder if there aren't some alternatives available, to make the View-code look prettier.

Perhaps some kind of extension-language or pre-processing formatting...

** EDIT **

Found:

- Spark
- NHalm

any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the existing engine to be prettier.... well, tough - it is what it is. You can try to take care when laying it out, and move common code into methods (perhaps extension methods on `HtmlHelper` for common code) to reduce the noise, but that's about it.

However, you are not limited this this engine - you can use **any** suitable template engine (or write your own).

- [Best Template Engine for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173207/best-template-engine-for-aspnet-mvc)
- [What templating engines are available for ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523644/what-templating-engines-are-available-for-asp-net-mvc-framework)
- [alternative asp.net MVC view engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649768/alternative-asp-net-mvc-view-engines)

Answer (score 1):

I found the Spark view engine cleans thing up.

http://sparkviewengine.com/

Comment: Spark looks really nice! :) 

I just stumbled over NHalm myself... have a look at it :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to avoid writing too much C# in your Views. They should contain primary HTML which should be readable. Also there are some [alternative](http://sparkviewengine.com/) [view](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/) engines to the default WebForms.

Comment: Granted... but you got the helpers... and I really think they look bad.. there must be a better way!